# Looking for help to use script in Sheets to avoid having equations in multiple sheets

Tags: macos, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using example [Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TlEHCnywTbu-W1NGDm2XACnR6gBG_3oQXg72J2W-bOs/edit?usp=sharing)

Looking to use script in Sheets to;

- Read active sheet name [e.g. RED]
- Look in SUMMARY Sheet and find matching sheet name in column A and read associated integer [e.g. R1C2]
- Multiply that by RED R1C1 and display result in RED R1C2
- I would want to be able to do this for all values in column 1 in RED, GREEN & BLUE sheets, either on opening or by using a button

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, publish your solution and ask about not working code. Nobody will program this for you here

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been voted down as you haven't shown any research or posted any of your own code. I'll help you out as I too am new here ;-). It is good that you have broken your request down, the next step would have been to start writing code... The following code will do what you have requested, bar it on running on open or by using a button. My advice to getting started with Apps Script would be to read through the reference documents and samples so that you understand fully what the code does.

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName();
    var activeSheetData = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var summarySheet = ss.getSheetByName("SUMMARY");
    var summarySheetData = summarySheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < summarySheetData.length; i++) {
       if (summarySheetData[i][0] == activeSheetName) { 
       valueToMultiplyBy = summarySheetData[i][1];
    }
    }
  for (var j = 0; j < activeSheetData.length; j++) {
    var resultOfMultiplication = valueToMultiplyBy * activeSheetData[j][0];
    activeSheet.getRange(j+1,2).setValue(resultOfMultiplication);
  }
}
```